# Some notation regarding "::"

Tags: notation

I'm reading through some geometry proofs, and I can see something like

$AB^2:PM\times EB::BC^2\ :CD\times PQ$

So I understand that $A:B$ is equivalent to $\frac{A}{B}$, but what does the $::$ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HINT

$$ A:B :: C:D \equiv \implies \dfrac{A}{B} = \dfrac{C}{D} $$

The notation is called [proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology).

> $A$ is to $B$ as $C$ is to $D$.

Comment: I wonder why they could not have just simply said A:B=C:D instead, which is much less ambiguous.

Comment: How is this a "hint"...?

Comment: Is $B=D=0$ allowed on the left hand side (at least when $A \not =0$ and $D \not = 0$) but not on the right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it says $CD \times PQ$ instead of $CD \times : PQ$, I believe the above statement is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\frac{AB^2}{PM \times EB} = \frac{BC^2}{CD \times PQ}
\end{align*}